# At what point are extension methods on POCO classes overkill?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

My POCO's structure basically goes like this:

`Person` which has: `Addresses`, `Phones`, `CaseNotes`, `NoticeOfActions`.

I started writting a `PersonExtension` class which I found quite useful with, say, the following example method:

```
public static Person GetPersonsPhones(this Person person, string userID)
{
    using (var context = ConnectDataContext.Create())
    {
        var pPhones =
            context.tblPhones.Where(phones => phones.PersonID == person.PersonID).Select(
                phones =>
                new Phone()
                    {
                        PhoneID = phones.PhoneID,
                        PhoneType =
                            new PhoneType
                                {
                                    PhoneTypeID = phones.tblAdminPhoneType.PhoneTypeID,
                                    TypeDescription = phones.tblAdminPhoneType.PhoneTypeDesc
                                },
                        PhoneNumber = phones.PhoneNumber,
                        Extension = phones.Extension
                    });
        person.Phones = pPhones.ToList<Phone>();
        return person;
    }
}
```

Now I have similar Extension Methods for Person that get the Address Collection.  What I am wondering is if there is a point where this is detrimental.  Due to the nature of my environment almost everything fits under `Person` in the `has-a` way.

Is that okay or is there something bad that I will run into from that?  Am I incurring WAY more overhead that way?

The alternative seems to be to simply pass the `Person.ID` since that is what I need to get the Phones from the DB and then add it to my `Person` object but that seems, to me anyway, to be the same thing.

---

I think there is a communication breakdown here which is most likely my fault as I don't always use the right words for things.

In my DB there is tblPerson and tblPhone.  I have a class called `Person` and a class called `Phone`.  My `Person` class has a Property of `IList<Phone>Phones`.
The Extension Methods in question are for CRUD methods for the child properties of my Base Class.
i.e. `Person.GetPhones()` fills the `IList<Phone>Phones` Property of that `Person` object.  `Person.SavePhones()` would `Save` any changes to the `Phones` to the DB for that `Person` object.

I am not arguing that what I am doing is RIGHT(*I doubt it is...:(*) just trying to make sure everyone understands what I am asking.
Also, I am using `LinqToSQL` for the DB access.

Comment: This sort of thing really ought to be in a repository, not in your entity class, IMO.

Comment: When I get **down voted** I appreciate some indication as to what was wrong with my question so that I can learn to do it correctly in the future.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 4):

Your person here should be a fully fledged [domain object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object), not a POCO. The person should [tell some thing their phone numbers](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), the person should not be responsible for going off to the database and fetching them out! The later applies whether you choose an extension method or not.

Regarding your question however, I see extension methods as way of extending some functionality of **third party code**. For example, you can do `ToUpper()` on strings. It would be nice to extend this to do Title Case. Here we are extending the behavior. We are "adding" to **third party code** without having the source at hand, because the alternative would be to introduce a new object that wrapped string to do so. Extension methods here then are only really syntactic sugar.

If you own the code, then extension methods are pointless because you can just make the method a fully fledge method on the class in question. The reason I say this is that with a proper method you can access private fields of the class you are extending, therefore using an extenstion method you are limited to public visibility, just like a normal static method.

Comment: There is another point for extension methods: If you want to add functionality to interfaces, like LINQ does.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a TextInfo.ToTitleCase() method that does that, though adding an extension method on string to call it would be good too.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare it was just an example off the top of my head, but yeah, it should be on string really for most use cases.

Comment: When you say they are "pointless in your own code" is there a reason that you should make it "a fully fledge method"?  Am I breaking a written(unwritten) rule by doing it or is there 'measurable' evilness that comes from using Extension Methods?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin no, there is no rule, but there is common sense. Why would you create an extension method if you own the code? It is pointless.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin I should have added, the biggest reason to add a fully fledged method is that extension methods cannot see private fields of the class in question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main downside would tend to be code organization. Isn't the point of OOP to try and keep related code together?

I'm curious why you are using an extension method here. If Person is an entity object, I would create a partial class that extends the entity class. Seems to be a bit better organization here to me.

Comment: I can see your point about code organization though the ability to write `Person.GetPhones()` is handy compared to `Person.Phones = BLL.GetPhones(Person)`  Person is just my simple POCO or possibly Domain Object as someone below pointed out.  `tblPerson` would be the entity representation that LinqToSQL generated for the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using POCO classes with EntityFramework code-first model, you should be able to write your POCO class like this (including only the Phones for now, just to demonstrate):

```
class Person 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

class Phone
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access `myPerson.Phones` directly and there is no need for your extension method.

Comment: I believe this is what I already have though I am using LinqToSQL not Entity Framework.  My extension method is for filling the Phones property with data from the Database.  Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin: Well, is the property declared in the auto-generated code from the Entity Designer? In that case, it *should* work without the extension method. Or did you declare it yourself? In that case, you can just implement the property directly instead of using an extension method. And even if you need it to be a separate method for whatever reason, it still doesn’t need to be an *extension* method — I believe the Entity Designer declares the classes as [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so just declare another part with the method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your class then you should write real methods for the class. Extension methods are useful for adding functionality to classes that you can't change, for example, a class from a library you don't have the source for and that you can't just derive from.

Comment: Extension methods are also useful for adding functionality to an interface, even if you *can* change the interface. If the new functionality can be implemented entirely in terms of the existing interface methods, it should be an extension method.